# How to open csv in excel with correct data in correct column?

Tags: excel, csv

[image: Data is off by one column in some rows]

When I open csv file in the excel, the data is off by one column in some rows but I remember it was correct in my database.How do I get my csv file show correctly in my excel? please help. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using? Try picking a unique identifier as your delimiter when exporting it from the database. Then tag only that that delimiter in excel when doing the import.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to export directly to Excel format instead of CSV, you can try find other database tool that support this feature. CSV should used only for simple table that contains no NULL value.